# Regex pattern for CORS origin domain

Tags: regex, qregularexpression

The CORS origin spec requires the origin to be of the following possibilities:

```
Origin: <scheme>://<hostname>
Origin: <scheme>://<hostname>:<port>
```

I would like to have a regex that can match origins with the above criteria; sample domains to match:

```
http://ex.bar.com
http://www.ex.com
https://ex.bar.com
https://ex.bar.ext:8080
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
(^(http|https):\/\/)|(www)|(?!.*(-)\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$:{0,61}
```

But this also matches domains starting with 'www' which I don't need and doesn't match for the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by constructing this regex:

```
^((http|https):\/\/)(?!.*(-)\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$|^((http|https):\/\/)(?!.*(-)\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]+:([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

The first part matches http://www.ex.com or https://go.ex.com

```
^((http|https):\/\/)(?!.*(-)\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

The second part is a port number check combined with part 1 to match the domain with a given port number, ie.

```
^((http|https):\/\/)(?!.*(-)\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

combined with

```
+:([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

I'm sure that might be a better way of doing this or representing the above, please post if someone does know. Thanks!

Working regex (needs to be trimmed down though):

```
^(\\*$)|^((http|https)://)(?!.*(-)\\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$|^((http|https)://)(localhost|(?!.*(-)\\1+)(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?<!-)\\.)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])+:([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

Comment: Disallow `http` altogether or you expose your users to this kind of attacks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgkj4ZgxI4c&t=21m20s